# Can't access subdomains on apache

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, dns, apache-virtualhost

My objective is to create 2 sites `site1.example.com` and `site2.example.com` in two VirtualHosts and use `/etc/hosts` for resolving.The problem is that I can access the main domain `example.com` but none of the two subdomains. My  hosts records: `127.0.0.1 site1.example.com www.site1.example.com example.com www.example.com`.

VirutalHost for site1.example.com

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/example/site1.example.com/html"
ServerName site1.example.com
DirectoryIndex index.html`
```

VirtualHost for `exmaple.com`

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/exmaple/html"
ServerName exmaple.com
DirectoryIndex index.html`
```

I've also tried without the main domain, make 'site1', 'site2', and 'exmaple' in three separete folders, configure hosts only with the `'siteX.exmaple.com` but still doesn`t work.No errors in the log, permissions and SELiunx are set correctly  I have not tried with proper DNS daemon.

I think the problem is in  my `/etc/hosts` configuration  and the two dots in `siteX.exmple.com` is not interpreted as a single record.

(The same questions on   ServerFault does not help)

Comment: There are a lot of spelling mistakes in that question. Are these typos reflected in the real situation, because if so that's likely why it's not working. If not, please fix your question to match reality.

Comment: I don't see a configuration for `site2.ex[am][ma]ple.com` in your question. Is there one? If not, that'll be why it's not working.

Comment: I've omitted the config for the second one because it is the same as the first

Comment: Your question didn't say so, so I couldn't have known that

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a virtual host configuration for your target subdomain `site1.example.com`. what you do have is a sure definition for `site1.exmaple.com`.

Fix the spelling errors and the problem should resolve itself.

You also don't seem to have any definition at all for `site2.example.com`.

Comment: The VirtualHost configuration for `example.com` and `site1.example.com` is the same and I have no problem with `example.com` so what do you mean by definition

Comment: You've got spelling mistakes. If that's the same as in your real situation then that is why it doesn't work, and there's no point anyone looking for anything different. Provide real data if you've got a real data problem.